# How to pass data from NSWindowController to its NSViewController?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have a `IBOutlet` of a `NSToolBar` button in my `NSWindowController` class, which is my main window class:

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: NSButton!

    // ...
}
```

I have a class `MainViewController` that is that content `NSViewController` of the main window.

How can I access this button in my content `NSViewController`? Is there a better way to organize the `IBOutlets` and the controllers to facilitate this access?

Comment: You should try creating a new project  and deselect "use storyboards". It will make your life 10x easier

Comment: Make a reference to your window controller object from your view controller. You can acess your button through the window controller.

Comment: Buttons generally don't belong in window controllers. If your window controller needs to respond to some change, that can be better decoupled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about like this using delegate? This example will change your button's title.

```
@objc protocol SomeDelegate {
    func changeTitle(title: String)
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    weak var delegate: SomeDelegate?

    @IBAction func myAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.changeTitle("NewTitle")
    }

}

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController, SomeDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: NSButton!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
        let myVc = window!.contentViewController as! ViewController
        myVc.delegate = self

    }

    func changeTitle(title: String) {
        myButton.title = title
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

To access NSViewController from NSWindowController:

```
let viewController:MainViewController = self.window!.contentViewController as! MainViewController
```

To access NSWindowController from NSViewController:

```
let windowController:MainWindowController = self.view.window?.windowController as! MainWindowController
```

Comment: There's no point in conditionally chaining if you're going to end up force unwrapping anyway. `self.window!.contentViewController as! MainVC`

Comment: Optional chaining hasn't changed since Swift v2.1

Comment: these solutions are not good. The moment the app is inactive the window is nil and the app crashes.

Comment: Just make it optional and check if not nil