# Setting up protocol and delegate to transfer data from a collection view does not work

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicollectionview, protocols

I've created a sample project in Swift that has a button and an ImageView as the layout. Upon clicking the button, it loads a collection view that contains a bunch of images. I am able to load the images and know what index it is located. I wanted to pass this information back to the original view controller and display it on my image view. To do so I created a protocol:

```
protocol CollectionViewControllerDelegate {
    func logoCollectionViewController(controller: CollectionViewController, logoImage: UIImage)
}
```

This protocol was defined in my CollectionViewController:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
```

I've also set my delegate:

```
var collectionViewDelegate : CollectionViewControllerDelegate?
```

And this is my code that invokes it:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var imageName = defaultImageList[indexPath.row]
    selectedImage = UIImage(named: imageName)
    collectionViewDelegate?.logoCollectionViewController(self, logoImage: selectedImage)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    println("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
}
```

On the original view controller,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CollectionViewControllerDelegate {
```

I wanted it to conform to the protocol and defined the function as:

```
func logoCollectionViewController(controller: CollectionViewController, logoImage: UIImage) {
    logoView.image = logoImage
    print("Logo Loaded")
}
```

However this function does not get called. How do I link my ViewController's delegate to the CollectionViewController that will pass the image information that i've defined in the protocol? Thanks for any help in this area as i'm stuck here and not sure what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad english, in OS X app i would do like this in your ViewController's viewDidLoad or override prepareForSegue:

```
let myVc = window!.contentViewController as! CollectionViewController
myVc.delegate = self
```

So I thin you have get some instance of CollectionViewController and assign that .delegate to self. Though, I don't know how to do that in iOS-app.

Here is my old answer same kind of quoestion, but in OS X [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916862/how-to-pass-data-from-nswindowcontroller-to-its-nsviewcontroller/28925238#28925238)