# How can I make an NSViewController communicate with an NSToolbar in Swift?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, interface-builder

I'm making a simple OS X app that looks like that in Interface Builder:

[image][image]

#### Backstory

The `MainView` is a subclass of `NSViewController`, and the toolbar is a simple `NSToolbar` I built with the Interface Builder. By default, the NSToolbar items are enabled, but they have no purpose until `Main Image View` contains a `NSImage`, so I want my `NSViewController` (`MainView`) to enable the Toolbars button when it receives an image, and disable them when the "Clear" button is pressed.

#### The issue

To implement the toolbar actions, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24810534/3997690), so now I have a `MainView.swift` implementing the `NSViewController` with the toolbar IBActions in it (and it works), so my toolbar can send actions to my view. But I have no way for the toolbar to receive messages from the `NSViewController`, because they are not in the same object: my toolbar is in the `Window`, my `MainImageView` is in `MainView`'s View.

#### Question

From what my search brought up, I should use a delegate, so I started making a simple protocol:

```
protocol MainToolbarDelegate {
     func setButtonsEnabled(to:Bool)
}
```

However, when setting the `var delegate: MainToolbarDelegate` in my `class MainView: NSViewController`, I have the same issue: I cannot point to the toolbar because it is not in the same object, and there is no segue linking one to another. I tried `var delegate: MainToolbarDelegate = self.view.window.toolbar` but Xcode returns me an error.

So now, my question is: what am I missing? That's the first time I use a delegate so I might be doing something completely wrong. Do I need to subclass my Window so that I could use segues?

Sorry again if my questions are not accurate, I'm completely lost.

Comment: I think it will be much easier just subclass NSWindowController. Here is one of my answer which is similiar to your case...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916862/how-to-pass-data-from-nswindowcontroller-to-its-nsviewcontroller/28925238#28925238

Comment: I figured that out a few minutes before your comment, and it seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Notifications!

Say you'd like to enable/disable a remove project button based on an action taken in the ViewControler. First you'll need to add some custom notifications (this is for Swift 3 on Xcode 8 beta 6, syntax and naming may vary for your version or the final version):

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let rowSelected = Notification.Name("turnOn")
    static let rowDeselected = Notification.Name("turnOff")
}
```

Next, you'll need to add an outlet for the button you would like to work with, as well as observers and functions in your window controller to handle the actions:

```
class SummaryWindowController: NSWindowController {

    @IBOutlet weak var removeProjectButton: NSToolbarItem!

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        shouldCascadeWindows = true
    }

    override init(window: NSWindow?) {
        super.init(window: window)

    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        self.removeProjectButton.isEnabled = false

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SummaryWindowController.enableRemoveButton(_:)), name: .turnOn, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SummaryWindowController.disableRemoveButton(_:)), name: .turnOff, object: nil)
    }

    func enableRemoveButton(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.removeProjectButton.isEnabled = true
    }

    func disableRemoveButton(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.removeProjectButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

and then you need a View controller to use to send the actions. In this case, it would be two buttons in the view:

```
class SummaryViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func onButtonTapped(sender: NSButton) {
         NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: .turnOn))
    }

    @IBAction func offButtonTapped(sender: NSButton) {
         NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: .turnOff))
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically Apple recommends you implement the NSToolbarValidation protocol here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/1658294-nstoolbaritemvalidation, but I find that it lacks some granularity in controlling toolbar items, so I opt for notifications like above.

Comment: @RyanCollins - the link is dead.

Comment: @SpaceDog https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/ValidatingTBItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000753